# Ensure new directory created

Tags: .net, multithreading, system.io.directory

I need to make directories in a folder from a multi threaded application.
The directory need to be unique for each session.

Now with file creation you can use the following, to be sure the current thread created the file.

```
New FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.CreateNew)
```

The `FileMode.CreateNew` gives an exception if the file already exist.

I can do the following. But if 2 threads attempt to create the same directory at the exact same time.
They will now receive both the same path. Because `Directory.CreateDirectory` does not throw an exception if the directory already exist.

```
    If Not Directory.Exists(DirPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(DirPath)
    End If
```

Does .NET4 have a solution for this?

Comment: How do you generate the 'FilePath'?

Comment: That will be: RootDir + UserName + Timestamp.
It should be unique. But I want a failback if it would not be unique.

Comment: If you just need to check that between threads of same process you can wrap the operation with [`lock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)/[`SyncLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/3a86s51t.aspx)

Comment: Why would you want a 'solution'?  A directory is shareable, it should not matter which Thread created it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the root directory is shareable. But the user will upload files. Each session in a unique directory.

Comment: Then each session should use a unique name. The problem should not occur.

Answer (score 2):

You can use global counter as part of your directory path:

```
private static long counter = 0L;

var n = Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
var path = 
    Path.Combine(
        root,
        Environment.MachineName, 
        n.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
        "whatever", "else");
```

Comment: The multithreaded application is in IIS, from multiple application servers. So a "locking" mechanism is usable in this situation.

Comment: @Stinus By multiple app servers you mean multiple physical (or virtual) servers? If this is the case, they presumably use local file system, so this solution will work just fine.

Comment: Could be multiple physical or virtual servers. Depends on which customer. The "RootDir" is on a network storage. So could be anywhere.
But it is 1 directory for multiple servers/threads.

Comment: @Stinus Then just shove `Environment.MachineName` somewhere -- these should be pretty unique.